# While retraining a pretrained model, getting: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

My model summary is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 31, 31, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 29, 29, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               802944    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 516
```

While I am re-training this model using the below function:

[image]

Im facing this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that you are trying to flatten an already flat layer. The output of your model is `(batch_size, 4)`, which cannot be flattened further. To simply fix the error remove the flatten layer from your code.

However, when fine-tuning a pretrained model, you should first **remove the top layers** of that model before adding your own. The reason is that these layers are trained for classification on a task different than yours.

If I were you I'd drop the last two layers of your pretrained model:

```py
# code same as before ...

x = model.layers[-3].output  # Flatten layer output

# don't add flatten again

for fc in fc_layers:
    x = Dense(fc, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

finetune_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion.
When i ran my re-train.py script, i have faced one more issue.


RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.

It says that the model needs to be compiled.
But as far i know, if i compile a model, all the previous trained data will be lost, and the model will be trained from scratch. I don't want this to happen because i want to use this model for further training purposes.
Can you help me in this.

model.fit_generator( training_set ,steps_per_epoch = 520, epochs = 20, validation_data = test_set,validation_steps = 2000)

Comment: Before you can use `model.fit()` you need to first run a `model.compile()` command. This requires you to specify the loss function and the optimizer. Also here you specify any metrics you want to use for evaluation. For example by running `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])` you're telling keras that you want to train your model on a cross entropy loss with the Adam optimizer and also measure the model's accuracy while training.

Comment: But as far i know, if i compile a model, all the previous trained data will be lost, and the model will be trained from scratch. I don't want this to happen because i want to use this model for further re-training purposes. Can you help me in this.

Can I re-train the model without compiling it and ,save it and use this model for future training ?

Comment: A model is initialized during its instantiation. You can't train a model without compiling it. If you want to retrain a model you have to load the weights from the previously trained model and then fit it again.